# Activity starts again after onResume()

Tags: android, android-activity, onresume

I am developing an app, when app starts, a screen shows up (splash screen), wait 3 sec and go to second screen. So when I use return button on phone or emulator, it goes to first screen and then waits 3 secs, then starts second screen again, so far it is okay.

But when I press return button while I am at first screen, I go to menu, but Timer/Handler event already started, so app starts again, even I am at in menu. App. starts because of initiation of second screen, after turning back to menu How can I avoid this problem? I don't want to restart the app when user goes to menu on their phone. I tried to do something with onPause and onStop but couldn't manage it. I need something like, if return from splasn screen, app must shutdown, I think.

Here is my delay code, PreAcilis is first screen that shows up, Acilis is second screen.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {

    final Handler handle = new Handler();
    Runnable delay = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Intent intent_basla = new Intent(PreAcilis.this, Acilis.class);
            startActivity(intent_basla);
        }
    };
    handle.postDelayed(delay,3000);
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
}
```

}

Comment: I think try get handler from "onResume" and put in onCreate

Comment: I did that, then app starts twice.

Comment: So the first screen is splash screen? or there are other things than image like buttons or anything?

Comment: Yes first screen is splash screen. App. starts because of initiation of second screen, after turning back to menu.

Answer (score 0):

As  what i understand ,, I think You need some thing like that

```
private Thread timer=new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{
            Thread.sleep(3000); 
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("Timer","Error");
        }
        finally{
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
});
```

And onCreate Method Use this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    intent=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    timer.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a CountDownTimer and stop it in the onDestroy/onStop Method.

Answer (score 0):

Override back button so whenever user press back button than you can stop the timer by yourself and then close the app.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   // Stop the timer
   // close the app.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) If you just want to destroy the handler (handler must be class-global):

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
            Intent intent_basla = new Intent(PreAcilis.this, Acilis.class);
            startActivity(intent_basla);                
            //delete callbacks
        }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

2) But, if you are only using the activity as a "splash screen":

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
            Intent intent_basla = new Intent(PreAcilis.this, Acilis.class);
            startActivity(intent_basla);        
            finish();
        }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

3) In my opinion, for just displaying a splash screen, use a screen-size layout with your views and display/hide it on `onCreate()` with a postDelayed. This way you can avoid weird navigation stacks by only handling 1 Activity class.

EDIT:

4) I'm using this on some of my apps and I'm not experiencing your problems. Launching this Activity, it shows a splash screen and 3 seconds later it fires the next Activity, nothing else:

```
public class PreAcilis extends Activity  {  

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.pre_acilis);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        public void run() 
        { 
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Acilis.class);            
            startActivity(i);

            finish();
        }
    }, 3000); 
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks but that didn't work, and yes first screen is splash screen I forgot the term.

Comment: In the preactivity, override the onKeyPressed and just finish the activity. Also remove the final on the handler declaration. This way everything in the activity will be destroyed.